# Would you recommend Eclipse over VS 2010 for C# Development?

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

I might have to address some development improvement projects in C# in the near term.
Presently, we have Visual Studio 2010 licenses available, but you are free to use whatever tool you like.

As I'm pretty familiar with Eclipse (and I like Mylyn), I'd like to know if someone here had experience with both environments and can share some insights or recommendations.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both have their pros and cons. Both have must-have features and I can't understand why you can't find them in both. But both can also be extremely frustrating in some cases. Personally I like Eclipse more, since I feel it is more flexible. However, this only applies to Eclipse/Java vs VS2010/C#. I don't think there's any way Eclipse could beat VS 2010 on its own ground. Most of the plugins I have tried for Eclipse simply suck. So I'd recommend VS2010 even though it requires some learning. And if you use ReSharper, it handles many of the weaknesses of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 20):

Go with Visual Studio 2010, no IDE can beat VS for C# development.
It will help you to have the best development environment. You will have all the needed wizards, tools, and etc... debugger is great. You can't have the same in Eclipse. You have almost everything you need for WPF, ASP.NET, WCF, WinForms ... and other type of applications.

Personally I have never seen someone or heard of someone using Eclipse for C#. I use Eclipse for Java and it is good for Java coding, but for C# it can't be as good as VS.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is a good option for C# if you intend to develop on linux with mono. But on windows theres no reason to not go with visual studio.

Of course eclipse is free and visual studio express has a few features missing. But in the business world stick to visual studio. Even then though I think I would take VS 2010 express over eclipse on windows. And like ignotico says Microsoft builds in a lot of useful stuff for C# and .NET development. Again if your using major parts of .NET like WPF or ASP.NET visual studio is a must. If your not using the big libraries and tools then development with mono on linux is an option.

I've heard trying to get visual studio to work properly in wine on linux is a nightmare.

Comment: Guy says that they already have the VS 2010 license. What about Linux, I think MonoDeveloper is the best idea.

Comment: for c# on linux monodevelop is much better idea.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to SharpDevelop when VS2005 came out and proved very fiddly to use for ASP.NET if you don't want to do it like an MS tutorial. It's worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is great for PHP projects as well.  It's my IDE of choice when working in the LAMP stack.  However, I suggest using Visual Studio for any projects involving the .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for Visual Studio but then seriously think of getting Resharper as well to give it all of the refactoring tools that you'd need (or at least most of them)